# Unit testing framework with background modes

Tags: ios, unit-testing, bluetooth

I've written a framework which makes use of CoreBluetooth background modes, but when unit testing I get the error

> "State restoration of CBCentralManager is only allowed for
>   applications that have specified the "bluetooth-central" background
>   mode"

even though I have the `UIBackgroundModes` key set in the framework info.plist and test info.plist. Is there any way to enable background modes when unit testing a framework?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't unfortunately